# implementing chapter 6 from yii books on another Project

Tags: php, yii

i don't see if that source code from the chapter 6 is usable , does anyone how to implement this on another table examples ??, i'd to see an example from you guys, sorry for my bad english :(

```
/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{ 

return array(
            'issues' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Issue', 'project_id'),
            'users' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'User', 'tbl_project_
user_assignment(project_id, user_id)'),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/about and edit this question appropriately or ask another one.

Answer (score 0):

See [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr) for more information on relations. The easiest thing todo is to create InnoDB tables, and create the relations/foreign keys in PHPMyAdmin. Once you have done that, create the model in Gii. Ik will create the Yii relations for you. You can then overwrite your code, or copy&paste from the generated code.